# How to get the closest point on bounds when I'm inside the bounds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bounds, collider

I’m making an VR game where the user can load a 3D model from a server and place tooltips over it to display info about specific points, so, I’m creating the logic to place the tooltips in a 3D space.

I need to get the closest point on bounds to create a vector between it and the tooltip’s attach point, so I can use that direction to place the tooltip without colliding with the mesh, the problem is, the meshes are concave most of the times, therefore the anchor point of the tooltip is inside the bounds, so Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds will not work properly.

Is there a way to get ClosestPointOnBounds when the position is inside the bounds?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/154676/finding-the-closest-point-on-a-concave-mesh) can help.

Comment: If it is actually about hitting from the inside not working.. you could use a trick and raycast from the outside, you basically just have to find the side of the bounds your given point is closest to, use those extends (and a bit more) and then raycast back to your given point -> the hit point would be the closest point on collider .. or you use ClosestPointOnBounds with that calculated position outside of the bounds